# Generalize methods for the application using JDBC template

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I am developing a demo application using Spring MVC v3.0 and the Jdbc template.In my application for different -2 module we need some same methods as save,update,delete etc..  .So instead of writing again and again same method for different modules.Do we have any way to implement this kind of functionality in a common class(abstract class).

Hope some buddy will give me the good way to learn and implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by having a super class with a save method that takes Object type parameter and then you have to check instanceOf and implement.But i suggest you to have different methods for different type.

Comment: Thanks for reply..can you provide me the example how to implement this.as well why you say to avoid this..?

Comment: As you know spring is mvc.You should have things moduler.

Answer (score 0):

create an Abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractDaoImpl<E,F> extends HibernateDaoSupport{

public abstract Class<E> getEntityType();

public void update(Object updateObject) throws DAOException {
    try  {
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(updateObject); 
        getHibernateTemplate().flush();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        logger.error("Error updating attachment: " + ex.getMessage());
        throw new DAOException(ex.getMessage(),Code.DAO_EXCEPTION);
    }finally {} 

    //To find by ID

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public E retrieveSingleMatch(F id) {
           return (E) getHibernateTemplate().get(getEntityType(), (Serializable) id);
        }


}
```

and the Dao Implementations

```
public class StudentDaoImpl<Student,String> extends AbstractDaoImpli implements MyDao {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Class getEntityType() {
        return Student.class;

    }

}
```

Your service code will be

```
    studentDao.update(anyDomainObject);
    Student student = studentDao.retrieveSingleMatch(studentId);
```

depending on your object ,

Comment: Thanks aravind,but i am not using the hibernate in the application.any other way using the jdbc template.?

Comment: The structure remains Anshul , even if you use JDBC template , all you need is extend JdbcDaoSupport and inject the jdbcTemplate in the super class . Remember to code to Objects in the Super Class . I don't have a ready code on this but I think it's strikingly similar.

Comment: But in hibernate all the tables are treated as classes and in jdbc we have simple table name and query.So how it works?